# turbodbc installation error in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, pip, python-2.7, virtualenv

I tried to install turbodbc with `pip install turbodbc` inside a Python virtual environment in Ubuntu 18.04, but it's showing this error.

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting turbodbc
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/7e/32673b7eb635354ad1d65b7d0935346554a33f949ccbc3cb8f70c3ea6912/turbodbc-3.1.1.tar.gz (77kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 650kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11>=2.2.0 in /home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from turbodbc) (2.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from turbodbc) (1.12.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: turbodbc
  Building wheel for turbodbc (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command /home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/bin/python2.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-Hg7XhF/turbodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-bqCHgK --python-tag cp27:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/cursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/api_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/constructors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/connect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/data_types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
  copying turbodbc/options.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
  running egg_info
  writing requirements to turbodbc.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing turbodbc.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing top-level names to turbodbc.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing dependency_links to turbodbc.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  reading manifest file 'turbodbc.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'turbodbc.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  building 'libturbodbc' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level2
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level3
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level1
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/turbodbc
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/turbodbc/result_sets
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/turbodbc/parameter_sets
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/turbodbc/field_translators
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/turbodbc/descriptions
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/statement.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/statement.o --std=c++11
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/connection.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/connection.o --std=c++11
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/column_description.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/column_description.o --std=c++11
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/make_environment.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/make_environment.o --std=c++11
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/cpp_odbc.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/cpp_odbc.o --std=c++11
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/error.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/error.o --std=c++11
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/multi_value_buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/multi_value_buffer.o --std=c++11
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/environment.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/environment.o --std=c++11
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/level2/string_buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level2/string_buffer.o --std=c++11
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/level2/input_string_buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level2/input_string_buffer.o --std=c++11
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/level2/u16string_buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level2/u16string_buffer.o --std=c++11
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/level2/level2.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level2/level2.o --std=c++11
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/level2/level1_connector.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level2/level1_connector.o --std=c++11
  src/cpp_odbc/level2/level1_connector.cpp:17:10: fatal error: boost/locale.hpp: No such file or directory
   #include <boost/locale.hpp>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
 > ERROR: Failed building wheel for turbodbc
  Running setup.py clean for turbodbc
Failed to build turbodbc
Installing collected packages: turbodbc
  Running setup.py install for turbodbc ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/bin/python2.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-Hg7XhF/turbodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-C72JEF/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7/turbodbc:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/cursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/api_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/constructors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/connect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/data_types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
    copying turbodbc/options.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/turbodbc
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to turbodbc.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing turbodbc.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to turbodbc.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to turbodbc.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    reading manifest file 'turbodbc.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'turbodbc.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building 'libturbodbc' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level2
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level3
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level1
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/turbodbc
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/turbodbc/result_sets
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/turbodbc/parameter_sets
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/turbodbc/field_translators
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/turbodbc/descriptions
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/statement.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/statement.o --std=c++11
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/connection.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/connection.o --std=c++11
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/column_description.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/column_description.o --std=c++11
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/make_environment.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/make_environment.o --std=c++11
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/cpp_odbc.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/cpp_odbc.o --std=c++11
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/error.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/error.o --std=c++11
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/multi_value_buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/multi_value_buffer.o --std=c++11
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/environment.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/environment.o --std=c++11
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/level2/string_buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level2/string_buffer.o --std=c++11
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/level2/input_string_buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level2/input_string_buffer.o --std=c++11
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/level2/u16string_buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level2/u16string_buffer.o --std=c++11
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/level2/level2.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level2/level2.o --std=c++11
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-3hk45v/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Iinclude/ -I/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cpp_odbc/level2/level1_connector.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cpp_odbc/level2/level1_connector.o --std=c++11
    src/cpp_odbc/level2/level1_connector.cpp:17:10: fatal error: boost/locale.hpp: No such file or directory
     #include <boost/locale.hpp>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/bin/python2.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-Hg7XhF/turbodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-C72JEF/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/user/.virtualenvs/chatbot/include/site/python2.7/turbodbc" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-Hg7XhF/turbodbc/
```

How can I get rid of this error? Any help will be appreciated.